# Graphs of greatest integer functions

Tags: functions

I've been asked to find the area under the curve [x+y]+[x-y]=5 with the constraints:x>=y,x>=0,y>=0(where [] represents greatest integer function)
I don't get it how should i go about plotting this graph.I tried it out in a different way-since [a+b]>=[a]+[b],using this,I arrived at 2[x]<=5 and thus got a reasonable curve to plot,thereby giving me an area of 3 sq. units.But this is an approximate answer, and I don't get to know the actual one.Can someone help me how to actually set up the parameters for plotting this curve, and how should I tackle such greatest integer function graphs in future?

Comment: I would rotate the plane by $45^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific example, I would sketch the first quadrant divided up into the places where $[x+y]=1$, $[x+y]=0$, $[x+y]=2$, and so on. Then I would sketch the quadrant again divided up into where $[x-y]=0$, $[x-y]=1$, and so on. Between the two pictures you should be able to identify the points where $[x+y]+[x-y]=5$. (The set of such points is not a "curve" in the usual sense, as it includes whole regions.)

"How should I tackle such greatest integer function graphs in the future?": in my opinion, this is a very weird problem, and I wouldn't try to make any generalizations based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the area that obeys your constraints.  A recommendation:  your function is more properly called the *floor* function, and denoted $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

[image: region]